# How to center title and set title font in a tcolorbox

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

Please help me set a centered, bold, larger font size Title in tcolorbox:

mwe:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!5,
    title={Top Title},
    coltitle=black, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries\Large, 
    sharp corners,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
]

  My box.

\end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had tried \centering and now realize my problem is I am creating an epub using tex4ebook (using tex4ht) and that is where the failure is.  I posted a new question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688072/tex4ebook-tex4ht-epub-tcolorbox-how-to-center-title-and-set-title-font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`halign title` determines the horizontal alignment for the title.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!5,
    colframe=black!5,
    title={Top Title},
    coltitle=black, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries\Huge,
    halign title=flush center, 
    sharp corners,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
]

  My box.

\end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This still does not center or change font size using tex4ebook to produce an epub...